# Saving loop outcomes in Julia programming language

Tags: loops, julia

I have been trying to learn Julia for I believe that it is a good alternative compared to the others that are in the "market"  nowadays. However, since Julia is a new language---and because there is not even one book out there to help the novice---, I start this thread here, although my question may be very basic.

So here it is: Assume that I write the following code and I want to save my results in a csv file.

```
csvfile = open("y_save.csv","w")
write(csvfile,"y, \n")

# Set up the function
foo(i) = i^2

# Start the for loop

for i = 1:20
    y= foo(i)
    y_save = y
    write(csvfile, y_save,",", "\n")
end
```

The code that I wrote before is from this site: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.julia.user/21070

Although I was able to make that work, I do not understand what I am doing wrong and the result I get in the csv is not readable.

I hope someone can provide some assistance with it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`write` function](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.write) writes "the canonical binary representation of a value to the given stream". In your case, this is the byte pattern that represents your `y`, which is of type `Int`.

You probably want the text representation. For this, you can use [`print`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.print), or even [`println`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.println):

```
for i = 1:20
  y = foo(i)
  println(csvfile, y, ",")
end
```

If you did not mean to break the line after every value (like in your code sample), use `print` instead.

(Note that in your first call to write – `write(csvfile,"y, \n")` – the text and binary representations are equivalent.)

---

You may also want to have a look at [`writecsv`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.writecsv) if you already have an `Array` of values:

```
data = [foo(i) for i = 1:20]
writecsv(csvfile, data)    # as a column
writecsv(csvfile, data')   # as a row
```